# how to set plugin repository in command line use maven 3

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin

how to set plugin repository in command line use maven 3?
such as:

```
mvn install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.pluginRepository.url=http://www.google.com
```

I tried this configuration, but it didn't work!